# JavaFX - How to prevent mouse clicking on TableCell from triggering its startEdit method?

Tags: user-interface, javafx, tableview

I got this class from Oracle tutorial but in my application I don't want to make cell edit function triggered when user focues on table cell by clicking mouse button but invoke it by other isolated control. It would be easy if only class contains some event handler but it doesn't and I'm stucked.

```
 class EditingCell extends TableCell<Person, String> {

    private TextField textField;

    public EditingCell() {
    }

    @Override
    public void startEdit() {
        if (!isEmpty()) {
            super.startEdit();
            createTextField();
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(textField);
            textField.selectAll();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void cancelEdit() {
        super.cancelEdit();

        setText((String) getItem());
        setGraphic(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (empty) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            if (isEditing()) {
                if (textField != null) {
                    textField.setText(getString());
                }
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(textField);
            } else {
                setText(getString());
                setGraphic(null);
            }
        }
    }

    private void createTextField() {
        textField = new TextField(getString());
        textField.setMinWidth(this.getWidth() - this.getGraphicTextGap()* 2);
        textField.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>(){
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> arg0, 
                Boolean arg1, Boolean arg2) {
                    if (!arg2) {
                        commitEdit(textField.getText());
                    }
            }
        });
    }

    private String getString() {
        return getItem() == null ? "" : getItem().toString();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so there is a TabelCell command called setEditable(boolean) that I think you should just set to false (assuming I get what you're wanting here) and then set it to true and give it focus when your isolated control is invoked. I haven't really messed much with TableCell.